# Nonlocal eigenvalue problem

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $k>0$ and $V$ be a positive and strictly decreasing function on $[0,kl]$. Consider the following non-local eigenvalue problem
$$
\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
&v_{xx} +V(x)\Bigr(v-\frac{\int_0^{kl}V(x)vdx}{\int_0^{kl} V(x)dx}\Bigr)=\lambda v,  \quad x\in (0,kl), \\[0.25cm]
& v_x(0)=0=v_x(kl). \end{array}\right.     (NLEP)
$$
It is easy to see that $(\lambda,v):=(0,1)$ is an eigen-pair of (NLEP) for any $k$. Let $T$ be the left hand-side of the equation with domain $H^2_N(0,kl)$, the usual Sobolev space $H^2(0,kl)$ with the boundary conditions $v^{'}(0)=0=v^{'}(kl)$. Then it is easy to check that $\langle Tu,v\rangle =\langle u,Tv\rangle$; that is, $T$ is symmetric. Thus, all eigenvalues of $T$ are real.  **The first question is to ask whether we can characterize $\lambda$ by the min-max principle**:
$$
\lambda_i=\max_{H\subset H^1_N(0,kl),\dim(H)=i}\min_{v\in H}\frac{\langle Tv,v\rangle}{\langle v,v\rangle}=\frac{\int_0^{kl}V|v|^2-|v^{'}|^2dx-\frac{\langle V,v\rangle^2}{\langle V,1\rangle}}{\langle v,v\rangle}, \quad  (VC)
$$
where $H^1_N(0,kl)$ is the usual Sobolev space $H^1(0,kl)$ with the boundary conditions $v^{'}(0)=0=v^{'}(kl)$. I kind of doubt this since $T$ is not "coercive"; also I do not know the existence of Green's function for $T$. More specifically, I do not know whether the following Green equation has a solution:
$$
\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
&T_xG(x,y)=\delta(x-y),  \quad x,y\in (0,kl), \\[0.25cm]
& G_x(0,y)=0=G_x(kl,y). \end{array}\right.     \quad (GE)
$$
Indeed, if (GE) has a solution (The trouble is the nonlocal integral term), we can write (NLEP) as an eigenvalue problem of the compact symmetric operator 
$$
\int_0^{kl}G(x,y)v(y)dy=\frac{1}{\lambda}v(x)
$$
as long as $\lambda\neq0$. Then (VC) is plausible by the theory of compact symmetric operators. 
**The second key and tough question I am asking is whether  all the eigenvalues of $T$ are strictly less than $1/k^2$ for all large $k$ and how to prove or disprove it**. Thank you!